# Using the tensorflow static library with qmake

Tags: c++11, tensorflow, build, static-libraries, qmake

I am able to use the static C++ tensorflow library in a standalone C++ program but not able to use the static library in a `qmake` project which depends on the C++ tensorflow library. I am using the linker options for  `-Wl,--allow-multiple-definition, -Wl,--whole-archive` but to no effect.
I am able to build both the standalone program as well as the qmake project but the qmake target **throws a runtime error**.

I compile my standalone program (test.cpp) using the following command:

```
  g++ -std=c++11 -Wl,--whole-archive -Wl,--allow-multiple-definition \
 -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-rpath,'$ORIGIN/lib' -Iinclude -Llib infer.o test.cpp \
 -ltensorflow_cc -ltensorflow_framework -o exec
```

In my qmake project, the target (**test** with multiple dependencies) is built with:

```
  g++ -m64 -Wl,--allow-multiple-definition -Wl,--whole-archive -Wl,
 -O1 -Wl,-rpath,'$ORIGIN/lib' $(OBJECTS)/*.o \ 
 -L../lib/debugL../quackleio/lib/debug  -L../lib/release \
 -L../quackleio/lib/release -L/usr/lib/86_64-linux-gnu -lquackleio -lquackle \
 -L../'$ORIGIN/lib' -ltensorflow_framework -ltensorflow_cc -lQtxGui -lQtCore \
 -lpthread -o test
```

Both these compile successfully without any errors. However, the standalone C++ program runs without any errors while the `qmake` throws the following **error**:

```
E tensorflow/core/common_runtime/session.cc:69] Not found: No session    factory registered for the given session options: {target: "" config: } Registered factories are {}.                                                                                              
F inference/infer.cpp:16] Non-OK-status: NewSession(opts, &session) status: Not found: No session factory registered for the given session options: {target: "" config: } Regisstered factories are {}.                                                                                                                                                                                  
Aborted (core dumped)
```

On digging somewhat deeper, executing the command ldd on `test` gives the output (simplied, shown only relevant libraries):

```
ldd ./test
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffda65de000)
    libtensorflow_framework.so => /home/rishabh/quackle/inference/lib/libtensorflow_framework.so (0x00007f85d34fb000)
```

While on running the same command on the executable of the standalone C++ program (exec), I get the output(again showing only relevant libraries):

```
ldd ./exec
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffd8e09e000)
    libtensorflow_cc.so => /home/rishabh/quackle/rishabh_code/inference/./lib/libtensorflow_cc.so (0x00007f8e45873000)
    libtensorflow_framework.so => /home/rishabh/quackle/rishabh_code/inference/./lib/libtensorflow_framework.so (0x00007f8e44cbb000)
```

From those outputs, it can be observed the **libtensorflow_cc.so** is not shown as a dependency of the test executable while it is a dependency of the `exec` file. However, both of them uses the same class `infer.h` as their dependency (the qmake target depends on `infer.h` indirectly i.e. it includes header file which uses the class defined in `infer.h` while the standalone C++ program includes `infer.h` as a direct dependency).

The code of the file `infer.h` is as follows:

```
#include "tensorflow/core/public/session.h"
#include "tensorflow/core/graph/default_device.h"
#include "tensorflow/core/platform/env.h"
using namespace tensorflow;

class NNInference
{
private:
        std::string graph_definition;
        Session* session;
        std::vector<Tensor> outputs;
        Tensor input_tensor;
public:
        NNInference(const string &, int);
        ~NNInference();
        float getOutput(std::vector<float> &);
};
```

Can someone please help me regarding what could be the problem here? How to use the `libtensorflow_cc.so` in a qmake project successfully? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error was because of the order of the included libraries in the build command for the `qmake` target! Using the order `-ltensorflow_framework -ltensorflow_cc` in the `g++` command works.

Answer (score 0):

If the order does not help fix. Use ldd on your binary to figure out if the lib dependencies are being added.

This changes based on the linux flavor you are using, but some versions of ld, will not link a library unless its is used.

In the tf case, tensorflow_cc was not being linked to my binary, even though I specified -l tensorflow_cc.

The solution was to add -Wl,--no-as-needed flag to gcc. GCC processes flags left to right, so specify this flag before you add -ltensorflow*

ldd  | grep tensorflow

---

A related issue seems to be the requirement of force loading tf on xcode. Using the force_load option. ( For a static lib )